# In Python Scan folder and subfolder and move file with same folder structure

Tags: python

I have a folder structure attach below. I have flatting PDF file form each folder and sub folder and save this on the different drive but I want to remain folder structure. Do this Only in python

```
├───ftpdownload
    │   └───04032021
    │       ├───Ahmedabad
    │       │   ├───aht
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_02_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_03_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_04_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_05_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_06_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_07_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_08_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_09_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_10_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_11_1_col_r2.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r2.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r3.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r2.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_14_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_15_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │       25022021_toibhoc_mp_16_1_col_r1.pdf
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───bar
    │       │   ├───brt
    │       │   ├───ngahm
    │       │   ├───rajk
    │       │   ├───srt
    │       │   ├───stplamir
    │       │   ├───sur
    │       │   └───toiac
    │       ├───Delhi
    │       │   ├───cap
    │       │   ├───etac
    │       │   ├───etaup
    │       │   ├───etcg
    │       │   ├───etdc
    │       │   ├───etdup
    │       │   ├───etj
    │       │   ├───etl
    │       │   ├───hdfr
    │       │   ├───hdgr
    │       │   ├───hdgz
    │       │   ├───hdnd
    │       │   ├───hdtha
    │       │   ├───nbtdez
    │       │   ├───nbtdoz
    │       │   ├───nbtfr
    │       │   ├───nbtgr
    │       │   ├───nbtgz
    │       │   ├───nbtmah
    │       │   ├───nbtnd
    │       │   ├───sntd
    │       │   ├───toidgr
    │       │   ├───toinoi
    │       │   ├───toiwagr
    │       │   ├───toiwbly
    │       │   ├───toiwdeh
    │       │   └───toiwmep
    │       └───Mumbai
    │           ├───bt
    │           ├───etgoa
    │           ├───etmc
    │           ├───etmp
    │           ├───etmup
    │           ├───etnag
    │           ├───etpand
    │           ├───etpu
    │           ├───mthpwk
    │           ├───mtm
    │           ├───mtnk
    │           ├───mtnkv
    │           ├───mtnvm
    │           ├───mtvavr
    │           ├───mumt
    │           ├───nbtm
    │           ├───toim
    │           ├───toith
    │           └───toivp
    ├───ftphotfolder
    │   └───04032021
    │       └───timesofinda
    │           ├───Ahmedabad
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_02_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_03_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_04_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_05_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_06_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_07_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_08_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_09_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_10_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_11_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r3.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_14_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_15_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_16_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │
    │           │   └───aht
    │           ├───Delhi
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_02_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_03_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_04_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_05_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_06_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_07_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_08_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_09_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_10_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_11_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r3.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_14_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_15_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │   25022021_toibhoc_mp_16_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │   │
    │           │   └───dt_mp
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_02_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_03_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_04_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_05_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_06_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_07_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_08_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_09_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_10_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_11_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_12_1_col_r3.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_13_1_col_r2.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_14_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_15_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │           25022021_toibhoc_mp_16_1_col_r1.pdf
    │           │
    │           └───Mumbai
    │               ├───bt
    │               ├───etgoa
    │               ├───etmc
    │               ├───etmp
    │               ├───etmup
    │               ├───etnag
    │               ├───etpand
    │               ├───etpu
    │               ├───mthpwk
    │               ├───mtm
    │               ├───mtnk
    │               ├───mtnkv
    │               ├───mtnvm
    │               ├───mtvavr
    │               ├───mumt
    │               ├───nbtm
    │               ├───toim
    │               ├───toith
    │               └───toivp
    └───olive
```

I use the below code but not helpful.

```
inputpath = '/121rawfile'
outputpath = 'c:/'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    # structure = os.path.join(outputpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    structure = (outputpath+dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    else:
        print("Folder %s does already exits!"%structure)
```

I try this code it help me create folder structure.but failed to process  PDF file.

**Edit**

In my folder structure on the folder is created with tomorrow date (i.e name is like 05032021 (C:\121rawfile\ftpdownload\04032021\Ahmedabad)). The root folder contains an old date folder also, So I Want them to check only tomorrow date folder.
Second I want change date after 10 am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the files

```
inputpath = '/121rawfile'
outputpath = 'c:/'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    # structure = os.path.join(outputpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    structure = (outputpath+dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    else:
        print("Folder %s does already exits!"%structure)
    for file in filenames:
        os.replace(os.path.join(dirpath,file),os.path.join(structure,file))
```

`replace` is used to move files, or replace them if they already exist in destination location. This is the reason, why no checks are needed if the file already exists in destination location.

To copy the files

```
import os
import shutil
inputpath = '/121rawfile'
outputpath = 'c:/'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    # structure = os.path.join(outputpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    structure = (outputpath+dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    else:
        print("Folder %s does already exits!"%structure)
    for file in filenames:
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(dirpath,file),os.path.join(structure,file))
```

Comment: I don't want move file,i want copy file

Comment: Okay, I did the move cause in the question you used the word move. Can you change it to copy.

Comment: Yes Sorry for typo ,thanks it working form me

Comment: @Aleem Hey, I added copy option too.

Comment: I have one more change.. In my folder structure on folder is create with daily his name is like 05032021 (C:\121rawfile\ftpdownload\04032021\Ahmedabad) so Want they check only tomorrow date folder.

Comment: @Aleem, as the new requirement is not directly linked with the original issue in this question, I can't edit here to answer it. A new requirement should be asked with new question.

Comment: You could describe the new requirement more detailed, in a new question.

Comment: New  Question Posted please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497660/python-scan-folder-and-subfolder-subfolder-only-process-specified-file