# Python Scan folder and subfolder. subfolder. only Process specified file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m doing PDF Flatting But the challenge is source pdf are store “c:\root folder\folder1\subfolders1\subfolders” every folder and subfolder have PDF and after pdf flatting done file save at different location but the Structure remains the same like that c:\ folder1\subfolders1\subfolders.
Example of folder Structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8uQ5.png)

**I am facing challenges because PDF Name is like that (06032021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf, 06032021_toibhoc_PP_01_1_col_r1.pdf, 06032021_toiind_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf)**

**Syntax of filename:- Date_Techcode_mp_pageno_edition_number_col_page_revisionnumber**

I need Only focus on Date and Techcode (i.e.  06032021_toibhoc) because this is unique in every file.
Case1:
I want to check the date if the filename starts with Tomorrow Date and Today date only process them.
Case2.
I want to check the tech code by JSON file. I have a store tech code which I want to fatten so the program should compare filename teach code with JSON file if JSON file tech code is present in filename only that file process otherwise it copies to destination without process.

**Example of json file.** `{"toiac_mp","toiac_pp","su_mp","rjk_mp","rjk_pp","bar_mp","cap_mp",”cap_pp”"}`

Case3: -
My working hrs is 3:pm to 2:am for I want it to change after set working hours

I try Following Code which process every file in the folder and from subfolders.

```
import win32com.client, win32com.client.makepy, os, winerror
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT
import ghostscript,locale,time,datetime
import threading


def convert_to_1_3(dirpath,out_file,org_name):
    ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)
    try:
        src = os.path.join(dirpath,org_name)  
        win32com.client.makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Acrobat')
        adobe = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.App')
        avDoc = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.AVDoc')
        if avDoc.Open(src," "):
            pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
            jObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
            jObject.SaveAs(out_file, "com.adobe.acrobat.ps")#com.Callas.preflight.pdfa
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        avDoc.Close(True)
        jsObject = None
        pdDoc = None
        avDoc = None

def ps2pdf(ps_input_path, pdf_output_path):
    args1 = ["ps2pdf", # actual value doesn't matter
            "-sBATCH",
            "-sNOPAUSE",
            "-sSAFER",
            "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
            "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3",
            "-sOutputFile=" + pdf_output_path,
            ps_input_path]
    encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args1 = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args1]
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args1)
    ghostscript.cleanup()

def write_log(file):
    start_time = time.time()
    current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S")
    current_date_and_time_string = str(current_date_and_time) 
    with open(file,'a+') as out:
        out.write(current_date_and_time_string+"\n--- %s seconds ---" % (str(time.time() - start_time))+'\n')
        # print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

def main(input_file,pdf_file):
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
            # structure = os.path.join(outputpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
            structure = (outputpath+dirpath[len(inputpath):])
            if not os.path.isdir(structure):
                os.mkdir(structure)
            for file in filenames:
                if not file.endswith('qxd.pdf'):
                    # shutil.copy2(os.path.join(dirpath,file),os.path.join(structure,file))
                    PS_filename='ps'.join(str(file).split('pdf'))
                    PDF_filename='pdf'.join(str(file).split('ps'))                    
                    convert_to_1_3(dirpath,PS_filename,file)
                    ps2pdf(os.path.join(dirpath,PS_filename),os.path.join(structure,PDF_filename))
                    os.remove(os.path.join(dirpath,PS_filename))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__=="__main__":
    log_file="\\PDF_1.3\log.txt"
    inputpath = '/121rawfile'
    outputpath = 'c:/'
    # t1=threading.Thread(target=main(inputpath,outputpath),args=(10 ,0))
    main(inputpath,outputpath)
    write_log(log_file)
    # t1.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling (06032021_toibhoc_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf, 06032021_toibhoc_PP_01_1_col_r1.pdf, 06032021_toiind_mp_01_1_col_r1.pdf)

First, you can read the Config file

```
def read_config():
    with open('/path/filename.config', 'r') as lookupfile:#use your path name 
        for line in lookupfile:
            tech= [word[1:-1] for word in line.split(",")]
            return tech
```

then you can use DateTime to get date and fnmatch.fnmatch to searches the file. Check today and tomorrow file you can use both

```
tom_date=(datetime.today()+timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d%m%Y")
today_date=(datetime.now()).strftime("%d%m%Y")
patterns=(tom_date+'_'+techcode+'*',today_date+'_'+techcode+'*')
if [pat for pat in patterns if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,pat)]:
       #do waht you want
```

If I am correct your full code we like this :

```
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch,ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT,winerror
import ghostscript,locale,time,fnmatch,shutil ,os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
def convert_to_1_3(old_pdf_file,PS_filename):
    ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)
    PDSaveFull = 0x01
    PDSaveLinearized = 0x04
    PDDocOldVersion = 0x0080
    PDDocNeedsSave = 0x0001
    SAVEFLAG = PDDocNeedsSave|PDSaveLinearized
    try:
        src =os.path.abspath(old_pdf_file) 
        avDoc = Dispatch('AcroExch.AVDoc')
        if avDoc.Open(src," "):
            pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
            pdDoc.Save(SAVEFLAG,PS_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        avDoc.Close(-1)
       
def ps2pdf(ps_input_path, pdf_output_path):
    args1 = ["ps2pdf", # actual value doesn't matter
            "-sBATCH",
            "-sNOPAUSE",
            "-sSAFER",
            "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
            "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3",
            "-sOutputFile=" + pdf_output_path,
            ps_input_path]
    encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args1 = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args1]
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args1)
    ghostscript.cleanup()

def read_config():
    with open('/PDF_Flattening/tech_code.config', 'r') as lookupfile:
        for line in lookupfile:
            tech= [word[1:-1] for word in line.split(",")]
            return tech

def main(input_file):
    try:
        tom_date=(datetime.today()+timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d%m%Y")
        today_date=(datetime.now()).strftime("%d%m%Y")
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
            structure = os.path.join('c:\\',dirpath[len(inputpath):])
            if not os.path.isdir(structure):
                os.mkdir(structure)
            for file in filenames:
                if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(structure,file)):
                    for techcode in read_config():
                        patterns=(tom_date+'_'+techcode+'*',today_date+'_'+techcode+'*')
                        if [pat for pat in patterns if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,pat)]:
                            if not file.endswith('qxd.pdf'):                                                    
                                PS_filename='ps'.join(str(file).split('pdf'))
                                PDF_filename='pdf'.join(str(file).split('ps'))
                                old_pdf_file= os.path.join(dirpath,file)              
                                convert_to_1_3(old_pdf_file,os.path.join(dirpath,PS_filename))
                                ps2pdf(os.path.join(dirpath,PS_filename),os.path.join(structure,PDF_filename))
                                os.remove(os.path.join(dirpath,PS_filename))
                    else: 
                        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(dirpath,file),os.path.join(structure,file))                        
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__=="__main__":
    inputpath = "/121rawfile"
    main(inputpath)
```